# Discharge peak hold capacitor with MOSFET

Tags: mosfet

I'm just thinking how I can discharge the capacitor of a peak hold circuit, by switching a MOSFET and connecting it to a resistor. Could anyone propose simple ideas with pictures/drawings?

Would something like this work?

[image: simplified schematic]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGoJ2X.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

With the limited information of the question, this is the circuit information I can provide. The ratings for the resistor and mosfet will depend on your voltage and how fast you want to discharge the capacitor.

The schematic that you drew will more than likely not work. You can't use a N-Channel as a high side switch the way you're doing it. You could use a P-Channel, but this is my personal preference of the way to do it.

Comment: Feedback for the first op amp should come from after the diode. Other modifications aren't that big of an improvement, but quite cheap as there's already 2 op amps used.

Comment: Agree with @Ralph. Change your first stage to be in superdiode configuration so that the forward voltage drop of the diode doesn't affect the charge voltage.

Comment: @Reinderien thank you for pointing that out. That was mistake when drawing the schematic.